# Is there a way to look at USER IDs that are the same, and then count entries within an hour of each other

Tags: r, datetime

```
   UserId             tx_date
23   1250 2016-05-06 08:35:45
36   1491 2015-06-27 03:34:45
40   1491 2015-06-27 03:48:15
44   1491 2017-05-05 03:52:47
48   1491 2017-05-14 10:52:34
52   1491 2017-05-15 06:01:12
```

Hi - So as the Title specifies, I'm trying to look at USERIDs that are the same, for example 1491 over the 5 entries, and count entries if the TX-date are within an hour of each other. I am really unsure how to tackle this.

So what I am looking for is to find that 1491 in this example has 2 transactions within an hour of each other eg

```
03:52:47 - 03:48:15 < 1 hour 
03:48:15 - 03:34:45 < 1 hour
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: this is perfectly possible. You can find similar questions on SO, or post some sample data (use `dput(mydata)`) and provide some data to work with..

Comment: You also have that `03:52:47 - 03:34:45 < 1 hour`. Do the entries need to be both within 1 hour of each other **and** consecutive?

Comment: Sorry -  I have just realised that the 03:48:15 - 03:34:45 example is not valid as it is 2 years apart. However, if they were on the same day, I just want to know how many are within an hour of each other, not consecutive, so the return I am looking for the user 1491 would be 2 (if they were on the same day) - in this case, the return I am looking for is 1. Cheers

Comment: `03:52:47` and `03:48:15` come from a different year, discard the dates, keep only the times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is called `df`, try the following :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(tx_date = lubridate::ymd_hms(tx_date)) %>%
  arrange(UserId, tx_date) %>%
  group_by(UserId) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(difftime(tx_date, lag(tx_date), 
                       units = 'hours') <= 1, na.rm = TRUE)) -> result

result
```

Convert `tx_date` to `POSIXct` type (if it is not already), `arrange` the data by  `tx_date` and for each `UserId` subtract current `tx_date` value with the previous one and count how many of them are within an hour of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two base R solutions. They use an auxiliary function `fun` to compute the time differences and whether or not they are within 1 hour of each other.

```
fun <- function(x){
  y <- as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), format(x, "%H:%M:%S")))
  d <- difftime(y[-1], y[-length(x)], units = "hours")
  sum(abs(d) <= 1)
}

with(df1, tapply(tx_date, UserId, fun))
#1250 1491 
#   0    2 

aggregate(tx_date ~ UserId, df1, fun)
#  UserId tx_date
#1   1250       0
#2   1491       2
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
  UserId             tx_date
23   1250 '2016-05-06 08:35:45'
36   1491 '2015-06-27 03:34:45'
40   1491 '2015-06-27 03:48:15'
44   1491 '2017-05-05 03:52:47'
48   1491 '2017-05-14 10:52:34'
52   1491 '2017-05-15 06:01:12'
", header = TRUE)

df1$tx_date <- as.POSIXct(df1$tx_date)
```